# If $Q$ is a dense subset of a topological space $(Ω,τ)$ and $A∈τ$, then $A∩Q$ is $\left.τ\right|_A$-dense. Does the same apply to closed $A$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $(\Omega,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Q\subseteq\Omega$ be $\tau$-dense. [We can show](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Intersection_of_dense_subset_with_open_subset_is_dense_in_the_open_subset&printable=yes) that if $A\in\tau$, then $A\cap Q$ is $\left.\tau\right|_A$-dense.

This allows us to make the following conclusions:

> If $\mathcal E$ denotes the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$ and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $(\tau,\mathcal E)$-continuous, then $$\sup_Af=\sup_{A\:\cap\:Q}f\;.\tag1$$
>
> Moreover, if $\tau$ is induced by a metric $d$ and $x\in A$, then $$d(x,x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2$$ for some $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq A\cap Q$.

Now, I would like to make similar conclusions for $A$ replaced by a closed $B\subseteq\Omega$. In particular, I'm interested in the case $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and $B=[0,\infty)$. Is there something which prevents us to make these conclusions? If not, how can we show $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: For $B = [0,\infty)$, things work, since $B$ is the closure of an open set. For general closed subsets, $B\cap Q$ can be empty.

Comment: @DanielFischer So, if $B=\overline A^\tau$ for some $A\in\tau$, then $\overline{B\cap Q}^{\left.\tau\right|_B}=B$, right? How do we prove that? Clearly, we know that $\overline{A\cap Q}^{\left.\tau\right|_A}=A$ ...

Comment: Hence $\overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau} \supseteq A$, so …

Comment: @DanielFischer How do you deduce $\overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau} \supseteq A$? I guess from $\left.\tau\right|_A\subseteq\tau$, but I don't see how exactly. Note that my definition is $$\overline{A\cap Q}^{\left.\tau\right|_A}=\bigcap\left\{K\subseteq A:K\supseteq A\cap Q\text{ and }K\text{ is }\left.\tau\right|_A\text{-closed}\right\}\;.$$

Comment: It helps to know how the closure of a set in a subspace is related to the closure in the ambient space. If $M \subset Y \subset X$, how are $\operatorname{cl}_Y(M)$ and $\operatorname{cl}_X(M)$ related?

Comment: @DanielFischer In the notation of the question, if $A,B\subseteq\Omega$, then $$A\cap\overline B^\tau=\overline{A\cap B}^{\left.\tau\right|_A}\;.$$

Comment: Right. So if you apply that to our situation, it's straightforward.

Comment: @DanielFischer The application of that relation was the first thing I've tried. At the moment, I don't see how it needs to applied here.

Comment: $$A = \overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau\lvert_A} = \bigl(\overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau}\bigr) \cap A$$

Comment: @DanielFischer That's clear, but how does this relation help?

Comment: $$M\cap N = N \iff N \subseteq M$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I forgot about your previous hint. So, sure, $A\subseteq\overline{A\cap Q}^\tau$. What I meant is that I don't see how we can conclude  $\overline{B\cap Q}^{\left.\tau\right|_B}=B$. The only thing I see is that $\overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau} \supseteq B$.

Comment: So $$\overline{B\cap Q}^{\tau\lvert_B} \supseteq \overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau\lvert_B} = B\cap \bigl(\overline{A\cap Q}^{\tau}\bigr) = B.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you four your help. I guess it was too late last night.

Comment: Overnight it occurred to me to ask: For which $A\subset \Omega$ is it true that $A\cap Q$ is $\tau|_A$-dense for EVERY $\tau$-dense Q? The answer is that $\overline B\supset  A \supset B$ for some $B\in \tau.$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, for dense $Q$ and closed $B$ we may have $Q \cap B = \emptyset$. The reason this does not happen for $A \in \tau$ is due to the definition of dense (for all open sets $U\in \tau$, $Q \cap U \neq \emptyset$). Further $Q$ is dense in the subspace topology on $A$ as $A$ open implies $\tau_A \subseteq \tau$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, let $Q$ be a dense open set and $B$ its complement.

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple counter-example consider that with the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ the set $Q=\mathbb R$ \ $\{0\}$ is dense and $A=\{0\}$ is closed and not empty but $A\cap Q$ is empty.

When $(\Omega, \tau )$ is a top'l space and $A\in \tau$ then $\tau|_A= \{B: A\supset B\in \tau\}.$   So if $Q$ is a dense subset of  $\Omega$ and if $\phi \ne B\in \tau|_A$ then $\phi \ne B\in \tau,$ so the $\tau$-denseness of $Q$ implies $Q\cap B \ne \phi.$ This may fail  if $A\not \in \tau.$

Comment: BTW. Here is an exercise that has some useful consequences:  Let $(X,t)$ be a top'l space and $Y\subset X$ where $Y$ is $t$-dense.  If $U\in t|_Y$ and $Cl_Y(U)=Cl_X(Cl_Y(U))$ then  $Cl_Y(U)=Cl_X(U)$ and $U\in t.$